# How to replace values of a column using a condition

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, na

I would like to replace values of a column when they are "42772" with NA.
I am using a for loop and then an if statement:

```
for (i in 1:length(wishlist$durationOnList1))
{if (wishlist$durationOnList1==42772) wishlist$durationOnList1 <- NA}
```

I get the following error:
    $Error in if (wishlist$durationOnList1 == 42772) { : 
    missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
    In addition: Warning messages:
    1: In if (wishlist$durationOnList1 == 42772) { :
    the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
    2: In if (wishlist$durationOnList1 == 42772) { :
    the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, durationOnList1 == 42772, value = NA) : 
  object 'durationOnList1' not found

Comment: Where is the `i` in your loop i.e. `wishlist$durationOnList1[i]`

Comment: I edited my code, but I still get an error : for (i in 1:length(wishlist$durationOnList1))
 {if (wishlist$durationOnList1[i]==42772) wishlist$durationOnList1[i] <- NA}

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up another kind of object. Try this: `wishlist[wishlist$durationOnList1 == 42772, ]$durationOnList1 <- NA`

Comment: Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, wishlist$durationOnList1 == 42772,  : 
  missing values are not allowed in subscripted assignments of data frames

Comment: Ok, your column has NAs, try this: `wishlist[!is.na(wishlist$durationOnList1) &  wishlist$durationOnList1 == 42772, ]$durationOnList1 <- NA`

Comment: Using your original approach with a loop, you should use your index `i` as akrun said: `for (i in 1:length(wishlist$durationOnList1)){if (!is.na(wishlist$durationOnList1[i]) & wishlist$durationOnList1[i] == 42772) wishlist$durationOnList1[i] <- NA }`

Comment: @JaimeCaffarel Awesome! worked. I am sorta novice here. Thanks